# I can't Insert row to database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying save to database row. But I get always error.

My code is:

```
function save_activation_key($connection, $username, $key) {
    $date = time();
    $is_used = 0;
    $query = "INSERT INTO account_activation_key (  key, date,  is_used)
    VALUES (    '" . $username . "',"
                . " '" . $date . "',"
                . " '" . $is_used . "')";
    $retval = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    echo $retval;
    $retval = mysql_query( $query, $connection );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }    
}
```

In `$connection` is valid connection to database.

Database structure:

```
id : int
key: varcha(45)
date: date
is_used: tinyint(1)
```

When I call my code I get error:

```
Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, date, is_used) VALUES (   'uzivatelsky_jmeno', '1459971829', '0')' at line 1
```

Where is a problem?

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you `echo` your query statement and check if it is valid ?

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
[and here is some help to decide which to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` is a MYSQL reserved word and should not really be used as column names.

> MYSQL Reserved Words List can be found here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

However if you wrap these column names in backticks you can get away with it.

You can also simplify your query string concatenation like the following, which makes it a lot easier to debug.

```
function save_activation_key($connection, $username, $key) {
    $date = time();
    $is_used = 0;
    $query = "INSERT INTO `account_activation_key` 
                     (  `key`, `date`,  `is_used`)
              VALUES ( '$username', '$date', '$is_used')";

    $retval = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    echo $retval;
    $retval = mysql_query( $query, $connection );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }    
}
```

> BIG NOTE
>
> Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
>   is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) *Which means this code will never run when all that is available is PHP7 or greater*.
>   Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
>   [and here is some help to decide which to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: only `key` is Smokey not `date`.

Comment: I knew you would pitch in with that comment. Arternoon Ralph @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Afternoon Smokey*

Comment: It is or was, but MYSQL provided a work around for `date` so I know you are correct, but I think it would be better not to use either

Comment: That was quite a ways back ;-)

Comment: Actually I can no longer find the bit about allowing `date` in the link I posted in the question. Can you remember where that is Ralph? @Fred-ii-

Comment: Probably in MySQL's archives. I can't go looking for it right now, getting supper ready.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Me too _Chef du Jour_. Never mind yo fixed the answer anyway.

Answer (score -2):

probably your query contains an error at the place where you are giving integer as a string , like your string 
'" . $username . "',"
. " '" . $date . "',"
. " '" . $is_used . "'

should be :
'" . $username . "',"." . $date . ","." . $is_used . "

the integers should'nt be with single qoutes  " ' "

probably this is the mistake!